# Splunk: How to split a field having multiple lines into individual lines and finally display in table format

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have Splunk field in the event which has multi-line data (between double quotes) and I need to split them into individual lines and finally extract them into a table format for each of the header. Basically, the requirement is to report this data in table format to users.

```
output = "DbName|CurrentSizeGB|UsedSpaceGB|FreeSpaceGB|ExtractedDate
abc|60.738|39.844|20.894|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM
def|0.098|0.017|0.081|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM
pqr|15.859|0.534|15.325|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM
xyz|32.733|0.675|32.058|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM"
```

I tried to use rex and multikv commands to achieve this. But, it didn't work. Looking forward for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, based on my assumptions about where the line breaks are.

````
``` Load test data ```
| makeresults | eval output = "DbName|CurrentSizeGB|UsedSpaceGB|FreeSpaceGB|ExtractedDate 
abc|60.738|39.844|20.894|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM 
def|0.098|0.017|0.081|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM 
pqr|15.859|0.534|15.325|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM 
xyz|32.733|0.675|32.058|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM"
``` Break the data at newlines ```
| eval output = split(output, "
") 
``` Put each line into it's own event ```
| mvexpand output
``` Break events at pipes ```
| eval output=split(output, "|")
``` Extract fields ```
| eval DbName=mvindex(output,0), CurrentSizeGB=mvindex(output,1), UsedSpaceGB=mvindex(output,2), FreeSpaceGB=mvindex(output,3), ExtractedDate=mvindex(output,4)
``` Ignore the header line ```
| where DbName!="DbName"
``` Display the results ```
| table DbName, CurrentSizeGB, UsedSpaceGB, FreeSpaceGB, ExtractedDate
````

Comment: I knew there was an easier way...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's quite complicated.  The steps are:

- rex it up into a field called `headings` and a field called `lines`
- rex `headings` and `lines` into multi-valued fields called `heading` and `line`
- zip `heading` and `line` into a `combined` field and mvexpand
- rex `combined` into `key` and `value` and then create dynamic fields and stat them all back into one event

rex it up into a field called `headings` and a field called `lines`

```
| rex field=output "(?m)^(?<headings>.+)$"
| rex field=output max_match=0 "(?m)^(?<lines>.+)$"
| mvexpand lines
| where lines!=headings
| table headings lines
```

rex `headings` and `lines` into multi-valued fields called `heading` and `line`

```
| rex max_match=0 field=lines "(?<line>[^|]+)"
| rex max_match=0 field=headings "(?<heading>[^|]+)"
| table heading line
```

zip `heading` and `line` into a `combined` field and mvexpand

```
| streamstats count as event_no
| eval combined=mvzip(heading,line)
| mvexpand combined
| table combined event_no
```

rex `combined` into `key` and `value` and then create dynamic fields and stat them all back into one event

```
| rex field=combined "(?<key>[^,]*),(?<value>.*)"
| eval {key}=value
| stats values(*) as * by event_no
| fields - key value event_no combined
| table *
```

Here is a run-anywhere example:

```
| makeresults
| eval output="DbName|CurrentSizeGB|UsedSpaceGB|FreeSpaceGB|ExtractedDate
abc|60.738|39.844|20.894|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM
def|0.098|0.017|0.081|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM
pqr|15.859|0.534|15.325|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM
xyz|32.733|0.675|32.058|Sep 5 2023 10:00AM"

| rex field=output "(?m)^(?<headings>.+)$"
| rex field=output max_match=0 "(?m)^(?<lines>.+)$"
| mvexpand lines
| where lines!=headings
| table headings lines

| rex max_match=0 field=lines "(?<line>[^|]+)"
| rex max_match=0 field=headings "(?<heading>[^|]+)"
| table heading line

| streamstats count as event_no
| eval combined=mvzip(heading,line)
| mvexpand combined
| table combined event_no

| rex field=combined "(?<key>[^,]*),(?<value>.*)"
| eval {key}=value
| stats values(*) as * by event_no
| fields - key value event_no combined
| table *
```